# c# Nombre de Form hijo activo en StatusStrip

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-forms

Tengo un Form principal con un StatusStrip abajo y un split container, en el panel 1  izquierdo un menu, en el panel 2 derecha es donde muestro los forms hijos.
Quisiera que cada vez que cambio de un form hijo a otro form hijo (active uno u otro), en el StatusStrip me aparezca el nombre del Form que tengo activo, el código para mostrar los forms hijos es el siguiente, dejo imagen para que se vea.

```
private void AbrirFormHijo(object formHijo)
{
Form fh = formHijo as Form;
fh.TopLevel = false;
this.splitContainer.Panel2.Controls.Add(fh);
this.splitContainer.Panel2.Tag = fh;
fh.BringToFront();
fh.Show();
}

private void Menu_Form1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
AbrirFormHijo(new Formulario1());
}

private void Menu_Form2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
AbrirFormHijo(new Formulario2());
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: cual es el sentido de mostrar el form activo en el StatusStrip abajo en lugar de quizas resaltar este en la opcion del menu de la izquierda, creo que reflejar el form activo en el menu es mas util que mostrarlo debajo en una barra de status

Comment: Hola Leandro, el sentido es por que me gusta así. Resaltarlo en la opción del menú izquierdo también me vendría bien saber como se hace. Gracias y saludos.

Answer (score 1):

Los forms tiene el evento

[Activated](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form.activated?view=netframework-4.8)

Con este evento conoceras cuando el form pasa a estar visible, es alli cuando teniendo la instancia del forma MDI puedes pasarle los datos

Para comunicarte deberias definir una interfaces como ser

```
public interface IActiveForm
{
    void SetActive(string name);
}
```

La cual implementar en el form contenedor

```
public class FormMdi : Form, IActiveForm
{

    public void SetActive(string name)
    {
        StatusStrip1.Text(name);
    }

    private void Abro_Form1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      Form1 formulario = new Form1(this);
      splitContainer.Panel2.Controls.Add(formulario);

      formulario.Show();
    }

}
```

Asi puedes obtener la instancia he invocar el metodo de la interfaz

```
public class Form1 : Form
{
    private readonly IActiveForm parentForm = null;

    public Form1(){
      InitializeComponent();
    }

    public Form1(IActiveForm parentForm) : this(){
       this.parentForm = parentForm;
    }

    public void Form1_Activated(...)
    {
        if(this.parentForm != null)
        {
            this.parentForm.SetActive(this.Text);
        }
    }
}
```

como veras en el evento `Activated` pasas el valor del form que se activa

---

Si necesitas en una funcion para abrir el form podria ser algo como

```
private void AbrirFormHijo<T>(object formHijo) where T: Form, new()
{
    T fh = new T(this);
    fh.TopLevel = false;
    this.splitContainer.Panel2.Controls.Add(fh);
    this.splitContainer.Panel2.Tag = fh;
    fh.BringToFront();
    fh.Show();
}
```

aunque habria que ver si te deja pasar el valor en el constructor ya que imagino va a necesitar que definas un clase base para esto, sino podria ser

```
private void AbrirFormHijo(Form formHijo)
{
    formHijo.TopLevel = false;
    this.splitContainer.Panel2.Controls.Add(formHijo);
    this.splitContainer.Panel2.Tag = formHijo;
    formHijo.BringToFront();
    formHijo.Show();
}
```

y lo usas

```
AbrirFormHijo(new Form1(this));
```

Comment: Hola Leandro, he probado pero no me funciona, he cambiado la forma de invocar los forms hijos. Saludos.

Comment: podrias explicar que no funciona? no se ejecuta el evento, no se pasa el dato al form padre, has puesto un breakpoint en el codigo para ver a donde llega

Comment: Siguiendo tu tutorial de http://ltuttini.blogspot.com/2009/09/c-comunicar-formularios-de-forma.html , parece que el problema es con el Show(this) y el owner, se ve que como el Form2 carga en el Panel derecho da error. ``` : 'Un formulario que no es de nivel superior no se puede mostrar como un cuadro de diálogo modal. Quite el formulario de los formularios primarios que lo contengan antes de llamar a Show.'
```

Comment: si estas en un escenario Mdi puedes usar la propiedad MdiParent para obtener la instancia del form padre, es lo que aplique en el ejemplo. El owner no aplica cuando usas mdi

Comment: No uso Mdi, es un splitContainer con 2 Paneles, el Panel 1 izda es el del menú, el Panel 2 drcha es donde muestro los forms "hijos".

Comment: ahh ok habia visto que usabas el MdiParent, voy a editar el ejemplo para adpatarlo

Comment: Leando, la ultima parte donde dice form.SetActive(this.Text); , ese form donde está declarado ?

Comment: `this` es el propio formulario, entonces le pasas el titulo que sera lo que muestres en la barra de estado, pero si quieres puede poner un string con el mensaje que necesites

Comment: Digo el form.SetActive , no me reconoce form, me sale en rojo.

Comment: edite el codigo, al aplicar el ultimo cambio olvide reemplazar esa linea

Comment: Buenas Leandro, ahora si funciona, pero tengo una duda, sería posible tener una función que sea la que lanza el formulario ? ¿cómo tendría que pasar el form a abrir ?

Comment: edite la repsuesta agregando como podria ser estas funciones

Answer (score 0):

Una solución sencilla es en tu Form principal declarar la porpiedad de tu StatusStrip como pública de la siguiente forma:

```
   //Este es tu formulario padre donde tienes tu menú, status strip y el spliter
   public partial class Form1 : Form
   {
        //Declaras el texto de tu status strip como público para que puedas acceder a él desde otros formularios. 
        public string StatusStripText
        {
            set { statusStrip1.Text = value; }
            get { return statusStrip1.Text; }
        }

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
```

Ahora en tus formularios hijos debes declarar formulario al formulario padre como pública para poder acceder al Status Strip de la siguiente forma:

```
   //Este es el formulario hijo
   public partial class Formulario1 : Form
    {

        //Aquí estas declarando el formulario padre como propiedad del formulario hijo, para que cuando llames al formulario hijo puedas acceder a la propiedad del Status Strip.
        public Form1 FormularioPadre { set; get; } 

        public Form2()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //Aquí estas accediendo a la propiedad del formulario padre en el momento que se carga el formulario hijo
            FormularioPadre.StatusStripText = this.Text;
        }

        private void Form2_Activated(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //Aquí estas accediendo a la propiedad del formulario padre en el momento en que es activado el formulario hijo
            FormularioPadre.StatusStripText = this.Text;
        }
    }
```

Ahora cuando vayas a abrir el formulario deberás asignarle el valor  del formulario padre para que pueda acceder a él el formulario hijo:

```
private void AbrirFormHijo(object formHijo)
{
  Form fh = formHijo as Form;
  fh.FormularioPadre = this; //Aquí le indicas al formulario hijo cual es su formulario padre para que pueda acceder a la propiedad StatusStripText
  fh.TopLevel = false;
  this.splitContainer.Panel2.Controls.Add(fh);
  this.splitContainer.Panel2.Tag = fh;
  fh.BringToFront();
  fh.Show();
}
```

Espero te sea de ayuda. Saludos

Comment: Hola Alfredo, he probado como comentas y no funciona, si te fijas fh.FormularioPadre = this; , eso se pone en el Form padre, FormularioPadre está declarado en el Form hijo.